# How do i deal with // URI prefix in tomcat?

Tags: java, http, tomcat, servlets

i am running a tomcat server which has filters (and a servlet) mapped to /xxx/*
I have client that sends //xxx/* at the HTTP header as the uri. as a result, the servlet and the filters are not getting called.
I have tried putting a filter at /* that catches the request, wraps it with a requestWrapper and override the getURI() and getServletPath() methods (they just return the URI with a single / to whoever calls)
That doesn't seem to work, so i am assuming that once tomcat receives a request it decides which servlet/filters should be evaluated against this uri BEFORE even sending it to the first filter.
Is there a way to solve this? can i make tomcat reevaluate after every filter maybe? is there another way?

thanks in advance

Comment: Please show us exactly what the requests sent by the client look like.

Comment: If servlet can't handle request uri starting with "//", that seems to be an odd deficiency.

Answer (score 0):

If the URLs in the request header are not conforming to the spec, Tomcat is doing the right thing by dropping them.

If this is the problem, you need to fix the client so that it puts proper absolute URLs into the HTTP requests.

"Hacking" Tomcat to make it accept rubbish requests is a bad idea.  It will limit your options for upgrading platforms, and/or deploying in different network environments.